# Cython import error 0xC0000005 with Python 3.4

Tags: python, numpy, cython, python-3.4

I followed 
http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html and
http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/interfacing_with_c/interfacing_with_c.html#id12 to use static types and cython to speed up some slow code with ~200x reduction in time, very happy.  If I use Python 2.7, things are great.

However I would really like to use 3.4.  When I run setup.py using Python 3.4, it appears to compile ok but I get a crash with 0xC0000005 exit code just trying to import the function in Python 3.4.

Below is a super simple example which has the same issue.

My setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import numpy
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext = Extension('hello_world', ['hello_world.pyx'], include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
setup(
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=[ext]
)
```

And the code to cythonize:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def hello_world():
    print('Hello world')
```

I am compiling with the command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Python crashes with only:

```
import hello_world
```

I am using cython 0.22 and numpy 1.9.2 on Windows 7.  Removing the numpy import and cimport from hello_world "fixes" the issue.  Any ideas on how I can get it to work with numpy as the real code relies on it?  Thank you.

- edit, I am also using Anaconda

Comment: @DavidW fixed the copy/paste missing quote error.  I am running setup.py with python 3.4 and I edited the question to make that clear.